# Jenkins parameter value not displaying

Tags: html, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

### **Goal:** Declare a conditional multi-line string parameter

#### Approach:

I have defined two jenkins parameters.

1. Active choices parameter
   [image]
2. Active choices reactive reference parameter(Choice type: Formatted HTML)
   [image]

In the pipeline, I am just looping over both parameters and printing them

```
pipeline {

   agent any
   stages {
       stage('print each paramter') {
           steps {
               script{
                   params.each {param ->
                     println "${param.key} -> ${param.getValue()} "
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the output

[image]

Second parameter is not printed. I have also tried echoing it with

```
echo ${inventory}
echo ${param.inventory}
echo ${params.inventory}
```

but it's not working.

Any suggestions how I can declare a conditional multi-line string parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Active choice reactive parameters rendered as HTML can be passed to build only if is hidden and formatted as input. See [Behavior and Rendering Summary](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/#documentation) in the official documentation.

The HTML parameters are only for visualization purposes, not for returning a user input value. For build parameters, use active choice and active choice reactive parameters.